# Radiobuttonlist and load page in same initial position

Tags: asp.net

I have this simple code in my page, I have a long page, if the client use this button then it shall reload the page and display the page from the beginning. I wish to be reload the page and display from the last position.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Value="45">Sheet2</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Any advice, apprciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback
```

inside the @Page directive

See [**Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)